# QGIS multiple descriptions from table

Tags: qgis

I would like to display all texts that are assigned to an element as a label.
Normally, the last hit in the table is always used as the caption.

*Description of the problem.*
There is a layer of properties. (polygons)
Each lot has a unique identifier.

There is then a linked table for this, which contains the owners.
The owners are also determined via the property number.

However, there can be more than ONE owner per lot!

How is an output by label with all owners possible?

### Table property

| lot ID | Gemarkung | Flur | Flurstück | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 099 585/10/259 | 585 | 10 | 259 | 1000 |
| 099 585/10/300 | 585 | 10 | 300 | 100 |
| 099 585/10/310 | 585 | 10 | 310 | 300 |

### Table Owner

| lot ID | Firstname | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 099 585/10/259 | John | Dow |
| 099 585/10/259 | Julia | Dow |
| 099 585/10/259 | Lisa | Simpson |
| 099 585/10/300 | Marge | Simpson |
| 099 585/10/300 | Homer | Simpson |
| 099 585/10/300 | Lisa | Simpson |
| 099 585/10/310 | Bart | Simpson |

Tables are already linked

qGIS 3.16.10-Hannover

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using one of the latest versions of QGIS3?

Comment: qGIS 3.16.10-Hannover LTR is used.

Answer (score 2):

Open "Owner" table in DB manager.

Create query:

```sql
  SELECT Group_Concat(Owner."Firstname" || ' ' || Owner."Lastname" ) as labels,
  Owner."Lot ID"
  FROM Owner
  group by Owner."Lot ID"
```

Load result as new layer - "Owners".

Link "property" to "Owners".

Use "Owners".labels as labels for your layer.

Comment: I think this only will work is the backend is mysql / mariadb..

Comment: And wouldn't it give "John DowJulia Dow" as label for the first parcel in the example? I guess the OP would like "John Dow, Julia Dow" - at least if it is to be used for anything else than an internal overview

Comment: Group_Concat create comma separated string as I know

Comment: It would be nice if all entries in table (Owner) were displayed for each entry in table (property).

is it possible for labels with the "expression dialog" to search the table by value or to be read into an array. The array could then certainly be output via foreach.

Comment: the solution works.
Duplicate values ​​are sometimes displayed. It is also possible that the table contains duplicate values

Comment: @Sven, if you are happy with the answer, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a database backend for your data, you may be able to do a query like the one @RainForest proposed, that may even be the best way of doing it, but the exact syntax may depend on your database backend. If so, please indicate in your question which backend you are using.

If you for some reason prefer to or need to do this entirely in QGIS:

It may be that you need to remove the join on the tables to get this to work. In the label dialog, press the curly E beside the value field to get the expression window and type in

```
aggregate(layer:='Owner', aggregate:='concatenate', 
expression:=concat("Firstname",' ',"Lastname"), 
filter:="lot ID" = attribute(@parent,'lot ID'), concatenator=', ')
```

This will just give you the labels printed on the map. If you also want to be able to search the labels, you would need to create a calculated field in your property table and use the same formula for that